# Cannot create IOS developement certificate

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-provisioning

For testing my app I try to create a certificate from apple developer account.
But under Development-  **iOS App Development** is disabled why this happens ?

I want to create a development certificate and then create a provisional profile

Comment: Check that you have the permissions to do so, I think you must be "Agent" (check in developer center under People).

Answer (score 0):

Open this [link](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/certificateList.action)
Revoke your previous certificate if you have, Then click on +
[image]

Then follow step